# What paint is best for asbestos siding?

Tags: paint

Is one type of paint better than another to paint over dark asbestos siding? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Any quality paint really that encapsulates the siding. The only change of my opinion in this matter is if oil based paint was used the last time it may be better to use oil, however there are many latex paints that work well over oil based with less prep work. Some require sanding a bad thing for asbestos base. If latex was used last laytex based would be best if the last coat is solid.

Comment: +1 for staying with same type as existing paint.

Answer (score 0):

Snow white paint, because it'll keep the house cooler.